# Debian: How can I use the command line to invoke a network interface to request a DHCP IP address?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, dhcp

The question is the title, but to elaborate:

I have a server with an Intel i350 T4 (4 port NIC) and currently 2 of the cables are plugged into my switch. One of the NICs has a DHCP aquired IP address. The other does not.

Why does my Debian 10 system automatically request an IP address for a single NIC, and how can I change which config settings to get all NICs to automatically aquire IP addresses?

Further details: The system boots into single user mode, but it does also have a remote desktop server running. (I forget exactly which one I installed - probably RDP? Remmina, on my other desktop system, thinks it is RDP.) I don't know if this is relevant, because it might or might not mean that Network Manager is being used to configure the interfaces. To be honest I have no clue how it is done.

Comment: I guess you have only one NIC marked UP at boot so it is just not enabled. you can manualy do  `ip yourcard up` & `dhclient`  again to try to get it during  diagnostic. Then force it to parameter file on NIC2  maybe in /etc/network. should be similar for your NIC3 and NIC4 if needed

Comment: `sudo dhclient` reports "file exists". What does this mean? Is it an error?